# Step functions dense in Integrable functions with respect to $L_2$

Tags: analysis, integration, normed-spaces

Let $I$ be a bounded interval. Prove that $\{\text{step functions }I \to C\}$ is dense in $\{\text{integrable functions }I \to C\}$ (Riemann Integrable) with respect to $\|.\|_2$ ($L_2$ norm)

Comment: Riemann integrable. A step function on $I$ is a function f=sum from k=1 to n of CkXk for some n>0, ci complex numbers, bounded intervals Jk.